# Non-sensible hypergeometric function being generated

Tags: special-functions

I was evaluating a sum, and Mathematica gave the following result:

$${}_3 F_2\left( -n, 1+\frac{a}{2}, -\frac{a}{2};1,-b;1\right)$$

where ${}_3 F_2$ is a generalised hypergeometric function, and the bounds on the variables are $0 \leq n \leq \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \rfloor $, $a \geq 2$ is even and $b \geq \frac{a}{2}$, all being integers.

What is strange about this is it evaluates to a polynomial in $n$, for suitable values of $a$ and $b$. However, everyone defines the hypergeometric function in such a way that it is undefined when any of the entries of the denominator are non-positive integers. Since $-b$ is always negative it should be evaluating to undefined, always.

Moreover, if we use Euler's transform (see below) that relates ${}_3F_{2}$ to ${}_2 F_1$ the formula involves having to take $\Gamma(-b)$ and of course this is undefined because $b > 0$. What is going on exactly?

---

$${}_{A+1} F_{B+1}(a_1,\dots,a_A, c; b_1,\dots,b_B, d; z) = \frac{\Gamma(d)}{\Gamma(c)\Gamma(d-c)} \int_0^1 \mathrm{d}t \; {}_A F_B(a_1,\dots, a_A; b_1,\dots, b_B; zt) t^{c-1}(1-t)^{d-c-1}.$$

Comment: Since `0 <= n <= Floor[b/2]`, `n` is smaller in magnitude than `b`. The `-n` term in the numerator gets to zero before the `-b` term in the denominator` and terminates the series before a division by zero can occur.

Comment: @BobHanlon this makes sense, thank you. But what about the formula I included? You have Gamma functions with negative integer arguments.

Comment: The hypergeometric series is defined with `Pochhammer` functions to avoid many of these problems with direct use of `Gamma` functions.

Comment: @BobHanlon Okay I guess I should convert it to Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: @BobHanlon So I converted the expression in that formula, in Pochhammer symbols it is $(-\lambda/2)^{(1+\lambda/2)}/(-\mu)^{(\lambda/2)}$ but this turns out to be zero for all the allowed values...

Comment: I suggest that you ask math questions at [`Mathematics StackExchange`](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Also note that you introduced `lambda` and `mu` in your last comment without showing any relation to the question or previous comments.